# Custom Create или произвольный дизайн формы

Tags: java, form

Возникла проблема при создании произвольного дизайна формы.
Накидал форму:

```
public class Form extends JFrame {
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JButton close;
    private JTextField text;
    private JButton submit;
    private JPanel imagePanel;

    private Decoration decoration;

    private JButton[] yesNoButtons = Helper.createButtons(JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    private JButton[] okCancelButtons = Helper.createButtons(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    {
        setContentPane(rootPanel);
        decoration = new Decoration(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                closeProgram();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setSize(800, 600);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int result = decoration.showOptionDialog(
                        Form.this,
                        "Question",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        null,
                        yesNoButtons,
                        yesNoButtons[0]
                );
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        });

        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("close");
            }
        });
    }

    private void closeProgram()
    {
        System.out.println("Exit Application");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Form frame = new Form();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Закрытие процесса приложения
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        imagePanel = new ImagePanel(Images.getBgImage(), true, true);

        close = new ImageButton(Images.getButtonImage(), true, true);
    }
}
```

Класс ImagePanel для произвольной imagePanel с которой проблемы нет. Задал картинку из ресурсов:

```
    import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    private boolean uniform;
    private boolean fill;

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>JPanel</code> with a double buffer
     * and a flow layout.
     */
    public ImagePanel(Image image, boolean uniform, boolean fill) {
        this.image = image;
        this.uniform = uniform;
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Rectangle rect = Helper.getAreaToFill(
                this.getSize(),
                new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null)),
                this.uniform,
                this.fill
        );
        graphics.drawImage(image, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        super.paintBorder(g);
    }
}
```

И проблемный произвольный класс для редизайна картинки:

```
public class ImageButton extends JButton {
    private Image image;
    private boolean uniform;
    private boolean fill;

    /**
     * Creates a button with no set text or icon.
     */
    public ImageButton(Image image, boolean uniform, boolean fill) {
        this.image = image;
        this.uniform = uniform;
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    public ImageButton(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     * FIXME: Not Drow
     * TODO: Process inactive buttons
     */
    @Override
    protected void printComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.printComponent(graphics);
        if (isOpaque()) {
            graphics.setColor(getBackground());
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        Rectangle rect = Helper.getAreaToFill(
                this.getSize(),
                new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null)),
                this.uniform,
                this.fill
        );
        if (isEnabled()) {
            graphics.drawImage(image, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, null);
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

И класс Images:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Images {
    private Images() {

    }

    private static BufferedImage buttonImage;
    private static BufferedImage closeImage;
    private static BufferedImage bgImage;

    public static BufferedImage getButtonImage()
    {
        if (buttonImage == null) {
            buttonImage = getImage("images/button.png");
        }
        return buttonImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getCloseImage() {
        if (closeImage == null) {
            closeImage = getImage("images/close_button.png");
        }
        return closeImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getBgImage() {
        if (bgImage == null) {
            bgImage = getImage("images/bg.jpg");
        }
        return bgImage;
    }

    private static BufferedImage getImage(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(Images.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде всё просто, но при дебаге в перегрженный метод printComponent() для ImageButton даже не попадаем, для ImagePanel фон картинкой применяется.

Comment: `printComponent` используется при печати (на принтер), исправьте на `paintComponent`

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена.